# Why doesn't my output work and keeps running when executing code?

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, gcc, output

My output isn't working since I tried (and failed) to use mysql with c on vs code(W11).
More precisely the program can get executed in the terminal, and only works in the output when I haven't put a function that asks the user to write something (scanf,fgets...) if I put a scanf, gcc compiles but doesn't execute anything and put "running".
I know I could just activate the run in terminal option of code runner but I would like to execute it in the output that I find cleaner and was working properly before.
Here is my settings.json file:

```
 {
      "npm.exclude": "",
      "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\include"
      ],
      "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
      "cmake.showOptionsMovedNotification": false,
     "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "notebook.formatOnSave.enabled": true,
      "notebook.codeActionsOnSave": {},
      "[c]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
      },
    
      "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
      "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "",
      "phpserver.phpConfigPath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.ini",
      "phpserver.phpPath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
      "launch": {
    
        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
      },
      "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "Visual Studio",
      "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true
    }
```

Here is the simpliest example which doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{   
printf("lalalal");   
int a;   
scanf("%d", &a);   
printf("%d", a);
 
   return 0; }
```

Here is what the output says:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Thiba\OneDrive\Documents\Travail\HTML\test\" && gcc lqla.c -o lqla && "c:\Users\Thiba\OneDrive\Documents\Travail\HTML\test\"lqla
```

and is still running, I have to stop it myself then I have:

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 118.666 seconds
```

Thanks for your help!

I tried to change the settings of code runner,

> I uninstalled and reinstalled vs code,
> I executed a program with the command prompt to verify that the problem wasn't from the compiler (gcc),
> I tried modifying all of the json file in my project (different from the global settings.json file),
> I tried opening another project/directory.
> I have seen several forums but the conclusion was just to activate the run in terminal option

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not show pictures of text. Instead copy&paste your text (code, build commands, error messages, configuration files) directly into the question using formatted text.

Comment: The problem is likely in your code, which you don't show us. Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. Copy-paste it *as text*.

Comment: It's worth noting that a fully-integrated compiler suite like [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is often easier to get up and running on, as out of the box it should work. Visual Studio Code requires a lot of patience and experimentation.

Comment: Thanks, @Gerhardh. I did as instructed, I hope it's more readable now. I have put a minimal reproducible example as well.